# block events when waiting for process to exit

Tags: c#, events, process, wait, exit

I have a Windows C# application app1 in which I launch another application app2, by clicking on a button, with :

```
var myProc = Process.Start("app2.exe", myArgs);
myProc.WaitForExit();//to wait I finish with app2.exe
```

This works great but I have two problems while app2 is opened :

1. if I clicked on app1 icon in the task bar, app1 goes to front which is normal, and app2 goes background.
2. if I clicked on buttons in app1, the corresponding actions are executed once app2 is finished. So app1 keeps in memory the buttons I clicked on and executes all the actions after.

So how to keep app2 in front, even when I clicked on app1 icon (I'm not sure it's possible as app1 and app2 are completely different applications) ?

And the more important for me is how to make app1 not responding to / keeping in memory events when app2 is opened?

Comment: You have just described behaviour of modal window opened by app1 as your required behaviour. So is app2 really should be a standalone application in your case?

Comment: Not really, with normal modal windows, the one which opens the modal window doesn't receive the events / doesn't keep them in memory while the modal window is opened. And yes, app2 is necessarly a standalone app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to disable all windows of your first application, as long as the child process is running. In addition, you can set the main window of your application as the owner of the window opened by the child application (should the child application display any windows).

If you provide further details about the technologies you are using, we can provide further help.

Comment: In fact, my app1 is a C# app and I launch app2 which is a separated standalone application (in Qt). But I will try your idea and disable the windows of my app1.

Comment: Finally, I disable all my app1 just by displaying an alert dialog just before launching app2. In this dialog, I put one button which closes app2 (kill the process) and the dialog itself. But I have a new problem, when I quit app2, I can't close the dialog automatically since the process.exit event (in which I wanted to close the dialog) isn't fired while the dialog is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the Form as suggested by Dirk Vollmar, but also use async/await with Task.Run() to pump the queue while it is disabled.  This will cause the app to discard all the user input while the Form is disabled instead of queuing it and processing it after the Form is enabled again:

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Enabled = false;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var myProc = Process.Start("calc");
            myProc.WaitForExit();
        });            
        this.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the

```
 `myProcess.windowstyle`
```

setting to start your app2 minimized or if I'm not mistaken even hidden `processWindowStyle.Hidden`.

You can also place your app1 on top by using

`myForm.Topmost = true;`

To make sure your app does not respond anymore to the use of the buttons, you can disable your buttons

```
myButton.Enabled = false;
```

right before you start app 2 and re-enable them after your 
`myProcess.WaitForExit()`
method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create it in another Task

```
app1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

Task t = YourProcess();
t.Wait();

app1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

your task

```
private Task YourProcess()
{
   return Task.Run(() => {
    var myProc = Process.Start("app2.exe", myArgs);
    myProc.WaitForExit();
    });    
}
```